# UICollectionView is too wide. How can i make it the width of the device?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I created a new UICollectionView in the storyboard. My problem is that the cells try and fit a larger width than the width of the device, so the ones on the right get cut off. What's a good way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pinned all edges of your UICollectionview...check out here

[image]

By pinned all edges, you'll get equal height and width of screen

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the proper constraints to your collection view. If you want it to be the width of the screen, then add 0 length spacing constraints to both edges of the controller's self.view (top and bottom as well if you want it full height).