# Autolayout, bottom layout guide with hidden offset

Tags: swift, autolayout, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I'm having trouble with autolayout I think. When I drop a view (in the example a map view) in a view controller, I make the new view fill out the whole viewController. Like this:

[image: Map View in View Controller, full screen]

It results in a screen looking like this:

[image: Map View without button strip]

As you see, the bottom om the of the map view isn't showed on screen. When I manually set the map views constraints to match the view controllers view, I can make it fit. But it seems like there is some hidden tab bar as default. can it be related to Simulated metrics:

[image: Simulated metrics for the storyboard]

This happens to all the new view controller I have added to this storyboard. 
Also I see a message in the view controller just before the map view, when I try to "reset to suggested constraints" or "add missing constraints", saying: "Failed to automatically update constraints", could these two problems be related?

[image: Failed to automatically update constraints - message]

Hope my question is clear enough...

Comment: I don't have any constraints. neither to button layout guide or to the map view. It has simply been dragged into the view controller, which has also just been dragged into the storyboard.

Comment: Yeah.. [Constraints on Map View Controller](http://i.imgur.com/KKkvubG.png)..
Maybe it's something from a previous view controller, that editing some common settings for all view controllers?

Comment: no its not like that....just pinned all edges of mapview like this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495323/uicollectionview-is-too-wide-how-can-i-make-it-the-width-of-the-device/30497767#30497767

Comment: I can do that, and it will work, but why isn't it filling the whole screen per default?

Comment: please accept my answer as it works...I added it for future reference for others